# unable to: receive user input "yes" or "y", flip boolean to true

Tags: java, string, if-statement, boolean

For some reason, I feel like this snippet of code should be easy, but it repeats the "would you like to..." message every time I enter 'y' or 'yes'. thanks for your help!

EDIT: Answered by @Keir-Simmons. The rLoop() method was fine; roundNum was being reassigned incorrectly, causing the for-loop before the method to be skipped entirely. Edited with correct code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int roundNum = numOfRounds();

    boolean repeat = true;

    while (repeat) {
        for (int i = 0; i < roundNum; i++){
            //other printing code
        }

        repeat = rLoop();
        //roundNum = 0;           //wrong
        roundNum = numOfRounds(); //right
    }

    if (!repeat) {
        gameSummary(wallet, wagered, totalWinnings);
    }

}

private static boolean rLoop() {

    String input;
    boolean repeat = false;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
    System.out.printf("Either [Y]es or any other key to exit.");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        repeat = true;
    else
        repeat = false;

    return repeat;
}
```

Comment: I think that the issue is the loop(?) that you're calling this method in. Although put in a breakpoint after the nextLine is gotten to check that it's correct.

Comment: What is the real name of your method?  `return` is a reserved word.

Comment: The code you posted only asks once for each time the function is called. If you want to know why it's called more than once, you'll have to show how it's called.

Comment: sorry rgettman, got shuffled editting the code for the site, the method name is originally rLoop();

Comment: No problem, please edit your question.

Comment: Please show us how have you called the method

Comment: And include the calling code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Now you have changed your code, I'll re-write my answer. What you have works fine. Try the following code and you will see:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    boolean repeat = true;

    while (repeat) {
        /* print game results here */
        System.out.println("results: here!");
        repeat = rLoop();
    }
}




private static boolean rLoop() {

    String input;
    boolean repeat = false;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
    System.out.printf("Either [Y]es or any other key to exit.");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        repeat = true;
    else
        repeat = false;

    return repeat;
}
```

It will print "Results: here", and print it repeatedly until you type anything but `y` or `yes` in response to the question. I'm not too sure what the problem is then.

You do not need the check `if(!repeat)` after the loop. The loop will exit only when `repeat = false`, in which case that if statement will always evaluate to true. Can I please see your `gameSummary` code?

Comment: It would be an answer if it didn't turn out that there was copy/paste error in the question.

Comment: Actually, it's an answer to the question that was given. Making that change to his code makes it run successfully.

Comment: Sorry! My method isn't actually called return(), I must have changed it while edited the code down for this site. Correction has been made. Thank you though!

Comment: THANK YOU!! You were right -- there was nothing wrong with the method itself; it was the for-loop in the main method that was being reassigned incorrectly, thus skipping altogether and jumping straight back into the rLoop() call. Thanks for your help!! I will remember to "string check" loop bugs more often.

Answer (score 1):

In `rLoop()`, if you enter "y", then the variable `repeat` will be `true` and the method will return `true`.
As it returns `true`, the `repeat` variable in the `main()` also becomes `true`,hence the loop doesn't end,which causes to call that function again.

```
{
 while (shallRepeat()) {
        /* do things */
            }


        gameSummary(wallet, wagered, totalWinnings);



}




private static boolean shallrepeat() {

    String input;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");
    System.out.printf("Either [Y]es or any other key to exit.");
    input = keyboard.nextLine().trim();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("y") || input.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
        return true;
    else
        return false;

}
```

Comment: but shouldn't it run through the rest of my commented code first, before it ran rLoop() again? (the commented code isn't actually blocked out in my code, I just thought it'd make is easy to read of this site)

Comment: @PaulChoi It should when not commented out. Is something there not printing?

Comment: @thegrinner yea, but for some reason, running all the code you see there results in the "would you like you play, [y]es or [n]o" repeating immediately one after another, even after inputting "y" or "yes". I am stumped :/

Comment: @PaulChoi It sounds like the problem is actually in the other methods that are commented out, if they're supposed to print something and are not.